# Why two bindings to the same function return different values

Tags: javascript

When binding a function to the same context, the resulting reference is different every time.

```js
function foobar() {
    return 1;
}

var foo = foobar.bind(this);
var bar = foobar.bind(this);

console.log(foo === bar); // Nope
```

1. Does that code copy the function every time?
2. Wouldn't there be any benefit in caching that behavior?
3. Is it implementation specific?
4. Or is it specified somewhere in ecmascript specification?

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5

Comment: @Vohuman please add an answer with that so I can upvote you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does that code copy the function every time?

Whether or not it copies the original function is an implementation detail of the underlying JS engine.

The return value of `bind` is a new function, and you'll get a new one each time you call `bind`.

> Wouldn't there be any benefit in caching that behavior?

There might be a mild performance gain to be had in caching the resulting function, but probably not enough to worry about unless you are generating hundreds of bound copies of the same function. Beware of [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Comment: I ran into that when trying to remove event listener and just wondered about how it is done, and what to expect in the future. As for caching I just thought about JS engine implementation, not one in my code. Wouldn't JIT benefit from just looking up previous references instead of creating a new copy every time?

Comment: @Misiur — What if you added a new property to the function assigned to `foo`? If `bind` returned the same object, it would also have that new property attached. That would be unexpected given that `bind` is supposed to return a new function.

Comment: Nice, that gave me a new look on that matter. Add that to your answer, and maybe get @Vohuman link from comment to the topic and I'll accept it when I can

Comment: Well explained @Quentin

Answer (score 4):

Yes the [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) creates a new function every time.

Comment: `.bind()` creates new instance of the function every time. And you're comparinge instances, so the result would be `false` every time

Comment: @MurDaD — No. It creates a new function. We're not instantiating constructor functions here.